# Running a node.js script with launchd

Tags: node.js, launchd

I'm trying to run a web scraper I made with node.js. `node app.js` runs the file successfully, but I cannot get launchd to run the script. Here is my plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>com.username.kijijiscraper</string>

  <key>Program</key>
  <string>/usr/local/bin/node</string>

  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/Users/username/documents/nodeprojects/scraper/app.js</string>
  </array>

  <key>StandardOutPath</key>
  <string>/Users/username/documents/nodeprojects/scraper/launchdOutput.log</string>
  <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
  <string>/Users/username/documents/nodeprojects/scraper/launchdErrors.log</string>

</dict>
</plist>
```

I then load it with `launchctl load /Users/username/library/launchagents/com.username.kijijiscraper.plist` which is where the plist file is saved.

Eventually it will be run on an interval, but for now I'm trying to test it with `launchctl start com.username.kijijiscraper`.

The expected behaviour - receiving an email based on the result of the scrape - doesn't happen, and no errors are in the log file. Again, the webscraper works from the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

You need start the service by:

```
launchctl start com.username.kijijiscraper
```

after load plist, or just append this:

```
<key>RunAtLoad</key>
<true/>
```

and this if you need:

```
<key>KeepAlive</key>
<true/>
```